# Correct way to pass useRef hook to ref property

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm not sure how to formulate the question less vaguely, but it's about **pass-by-value** and **pass-by-reference** cases in react. And Hooks.

*I am using gsap to animate a div slide-in and out is the context for this, but I'm going to guess that what the ref is used for shouldn't matter.*

---

So, this works fine, even though this is a more class-component-typical way of passing a ref as i understand it:

```
const RootNavigation = () => {
var navbar = useRef();

const myTween = new TimelineLite({ paused: true });    
const animate = () => {
    myTween.to(navbar, 0.07, { x: "100" }).play();
  };

return(
     <div className="nav-main" ref={div => (navbar = div)}>   // <<<<<<<<<<   pass as a callback
     ...
    </div>
    )}
```

And this elicits a "TypeError: Cannot add property _gsap, object is not extensible" error, even though this is how the React Hooks guide would have me do it:

```
const RootNavigation = () => {
var navbar = useRef();

const myTween = new TimelineLite({ paused: true });    
const animate = () => {
    myTween.to(navbar, 0.07, { x: "100" }).play();
  };

return(
     <div className="nav-main" ref={navbar}>          //<<<<<<<<<<<<<  not passing a callback
     ...
    </div>
    )}
```

Could somebody explain to me what's going on here or even toss a boy a link to where it's already been explained? I'm sure some sort of Dan character has written about it somewhere, i'm just not sure what to google. Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the first example you aren't using a `ref`, you are reassigning `navbar` through the `ref` callback so `navbar` is the DOM element.

It's the same as

```js
let navbar = null;

return <div ref={node => (navbar = node)} />
```

In the second example you are using the `ref` **object** which is an object with a `current` property that holds the DOM element

```js
const navbar = useRef(null)

return <div ref={navbar} />
```

navbar is now

```js
{ current: the DOM element }
```

So you are passing the object into `myTween.to()` instead of the DOM element inside `navbar.current`

Now in the second example `gsap` is trying to extend the `ref` object itself and not the DOM element.

**Why do we get the TypeError: Cannot add property _gsap, object is not extensible`?**

If you look at the source code of [`useRef`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L888) you will see on line `891`

```js
if (__DEV__) {
  Object.seal(ref);
}
```

that React is sealing the `ref` object and `JavaScript` will throw an error when we try to extend it using `Object.defineProperty()` which is probably what `gsap` is doing.

The solution for using a `ref` will be to pass `ref.current` into `tween.to()`

```js
const RootNavigation = () => {
  const navbar = useRef()

  const myTween = new TimelineLite({ paused: true });   

  const animate = () => {
    myTween.to(navbar.current, 0.07, { x: "100" }).play()
  }

  return (
    <div className="nav-main" ref={navbar}>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```